# CSS drop down menu appearing behind an image

Tags: css

On chrome the drop down menu appears behind the top most image at this page I am playing with.

http://www.audiobookreviews.com/genre2.php

I messed with the z-axis and set all z-axis for the menu to 999, then also tried making the image bigger/smaller but still happens.

Comment: drop down menu appears behind the top most image-- Which menu and which image??

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/viAGuzq  In this image we see that if I inspect the element then put in z-index of 999 in chrome, then the menu does go in front correctly, but I make the change to my css file re-upload and try it again but there is still the problem, liker here: https://imgur.com/a/ZuCQCa5

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which are basically: go look at my site and fix it, are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking. Please see: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `center` tag with `section` since `center` is obsolete. You need to set your element's `z-index` in such a way that element that has to appear on top has higher value of it. Something like this:

```
.w3-dropdown-content {
    z-index: 999;
}
section {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

P.S. I know you provided a link to your website but it's more useful to have a certain chunk of code you are refering to posted here.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Where can I find this though, I do not see anything like that in my .css file?

Comment: You are adding css with those styles on line 84 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`. You can add it in other css that is being added below line 84 or download this file, store it locally and modify.